# Error saying.No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am facing an error while accesing data from database table saying `InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.`
I have used generic repository pattern. I have my DbContext i.e BlazorContext and model class in seperate class library project.

Any help will be grate.
Below is my connection string in appsettings.json

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
"myconn": "server=DESKTOP-VM2VP34; database=BlazorDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },<br><br>
```

Below is my startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<BlazorContext>(item => item.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("myconn")));
```

Below is my DbContext i.e BlazorContext

```
namespace Blazor.Model.Models
{
public class BlazorContext:DbContext
{
    public BlazorContext()
    {
    }

    public BlazorContext(DbContextOptions<BlazorContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
}
```

Below is my generic repository implementation where it show error

```
namespace Blazor.Repository.Implementation
{
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected BlazorContext _entities;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbset; // error in this line

    public GenericRepository(BlazorContext context)
    {
        _entities = context;
        _dbset = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbset.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
}
```

Below is my GenericUnitOfWork

```
namespace Blazor.Repository.Implementation
{
public sealed class GenericUnitOfWork : IGenericUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private BlazorContext entities = null;
    public GenericUnitOfWork()
    {
        entities = new BlazorContext();
    }

    public Dictionary<Type, object> repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public IGenericRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)) == true)
        {
            return repositories[typeof(T)] as IGenericRepository<T>;
        }
        var t = typeof(T);

        IGenericRepository<T> repo = new GenericRepository<T>(entities);//error in this line
        repositories.Add(typeof(T), repo);
        return repo;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your unit of work manually creates a DB context using the parameterless constructor. That's incorrect because you won't get the context configured by startup and a very poor general practice. Your unit of work should have its context injected. Then register the unit of work as a service

Comment: @AluanHaddad : can you help me with my code please

Comment: I could but I would suggest you scrap your whole DAO pattern. `DbSet<T>` is already a generic repository - Wrapping it is counterproductive , awkward, and unnecessary. Likewise `BlazorContext` is, as a subtype of `DbContext`, already a unit of work service. Use these types directly, especially if you are new to the framework

Comment: I know this is old but I ran into the same problem.  My data access repository project is separate from my service project.  The service project was a console application.  When I ran the add-migration with the -startupproject targeting the console app, it didn't work.  When I targeted a web app with the same startup code - it worked. I wonder if it has something to do with the way the EF Core tools inspect the startup project.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string template is not correct for the MS SQL server. Try to use something like this:

```
"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=BlazorDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;"
```

If it doesn't work then you use not MS SQL server and so  in your startup you have to replace "item => item.UseSqlServer" with other provider.